# Portable Class Library Read Settings Info

Tags: c#, portable-class-library, application-settings

I have a portable class library that I need to get at the application that is hosting it's settings.

(i.e. web.config, app.config or Windows (phone) 8 settings wherever those are stored)

Is there a way to do this .I've been searching like crazy and can't find anything that allows me to read this information, and I can't find anything that will tell me where the application config file is located even.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to agnostic-ally read application settings in a PCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly from a portable library.  I'd recommend using the abstraction pattern.  Create an interface (ie IApplicationSettings or something) encapsulating the functionality you need to access.  Then in a platform-specific library for each platform implement that interface using the platform-specific settings APIs.  Pass an instance of the implementation from platform-specific code to the portable code so it can access that functionality.

More details can be found in this blog post: [How to Make Portable Class Libraries Work for You](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Create a public class in your PCL with members for the data your PCL needs. Have the apps that consume your PCL libraries populate an instance of that class with the data you need from their environment and give it to the PCL code that needs those values.

Answer (score 2):

**It's possible:** I have implemented a PCL library which provides exactly what you are looking for. Have a look at:

- https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/ApplicationSettings

The class works for WinRT, WP8 and WPF/desktop apps. Internally it uses reflection to call the correct api depending on the current platform.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to read these settings from within a portable class library.

You could instantiate a custom class within your PCL and fill it from outside.